# Split content into flexible numner of columns

Tags: css, html, web

For the last few hours, I have been trying to come up with a solution to the following problem. I have a very text-heavy website using a simple 2 column layout containing of a fixed-width sidebar and a content column that fills the rest rest of the space. With this setup, on most desktop resolutions, the content area will be quite large. The text is organized in many relatively short sections so having it just flow normally is not very pleasant on the eye, most solutions I have found seem to be newspaper-style layout that organizes articles like this:
(|m| = fixed width side bar):

```
|m| |s1 s3|
|m| |s2 s4| 
|m| |s5 ..|
```

rather than the desired

```
|m| |s1 s2|
|m| |s3 s4|
|m| |s5 ..|
```

If the screen size grows sufficiently small (below a certain threshold), the content should fold into 1 column.

```
|m| |a1|
|m| |a2|
|m| |a3|
|m| |..|
```

CSS3's **column-count** combined with column-width seems to do what I want, except that content is ordered by column as shown in the first example, which is not desirable. **Flexbox** is able to order content by row but I did not manage to make columns that have uniform width across their entire height, while also maintaining the required flexibility of the content.

The website is for a limited, known subset of people, so a HTML5/CSS3-only solution, or solutions that break in older versions of Chrome/Firefox/IE are perfectly fine.

CSS used to achieve the layout:

```
#siteWrapper { /* wraps #contentColumWrapper & #sidebarColumn
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#contentColumnWrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
 }
#contentColumn {
   margin-left: 210px; /* Based on sidebar width */
}   
#sidebarColumn {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: -100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="siteHeader"> ...</div> 
<div id="siteWrapper">  
  <div id="contentColumnWrapper">
    <div id="contentColumn" >
      <div id="...">...</div>
      <div id="...">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sideBar>..</div>
</div>
<div id="siteFooter>..</div>
```

The closest I have come is the following flex layout, with a script adjusting the flex-basis depending on the content's width, setting it to either half or full width. The major issue is that flexbox doesn't seem to deal well with heights.

```
.contentColumn {    
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.contentColumn div {
    flex-basis: 0px; /* set by JavaScript */
}
```

There is a major problem with it though, say you have a column that has much less text than the others. As an example:
A:300px, B:150px, C:150px, D:150px, E: 150px, the layout is going to be,

```
|A B|
|A  |
|C D|
```

Creating a huge amount of blank vertical space, when it should be,something like this:

```
|A B|
|A C|
|D E|
```

Comment: put here a code which you have tried!!

Comment: Edited main post to include current solution, and the problem that it creates.

Comment: did you see the answer ?!

Answer (score 0):

I hope This is what you need:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
 body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #666;
}
/* STRUCTURE */

#pagewrap {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
#header {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
#sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
#r-side {
  float: left;
  width: 66%;
}
#first {
  width: 295px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
#second {
  width: 295px;
  /* Account for margins + border values */
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
#third {
  width: 295px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
#forth {
  width: 295px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  float: left;
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
/************************************************************************************
MEDIA QUERIES
*************************************************************************************/

/* for 980px or less */

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  #pagewrap {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #r-side {
    width: 49%;
  }
  #sidebar {
    width: 44%;
  }
  #first {
    clear: both;
    padding: 1% 4%;
    width: auto;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #second {
    clear: both;
    padding: 1% 4%;
    width: auto;
    float: none;
  }
  #third {
    clear: both;
    padding: 1% 4%;
    width: auto;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #forth {
    clear: both;
    padding: 1% 4%;
    width: auto;
    float: none;
  }
  #header,
  #footer {
    padding: 1% 4%;
  }
}
/* for 700px or less */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #sidebar {
    width: 45%;
  }
  #r-side {
    width: 45%;
  }
  #first {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
  }
  #second {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
  }
  #third {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
  }
  #forth {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
  }
}
/* for 480px or less */

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #header {
    height: auto;
  }
  #sidebar {
    width: 42%;
  }
  #r-side {
    width: 42%;
  }
}
#first {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
#sidebar {
  background: #f0efef;
}
#header,
#first,
#second,
#third,
#forth {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#pagewrap,
#header,
#first,
#second,
#third,
#forth,
#sidebar,
#footer {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="pagewrap">

  <div id="header">
    <h1>Responsive Layout</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <h2>This is Siderbar</h2>
    <p>The Test text goes here</p>
  </div>
  <div id="r-side">
    <div id="first">
      <h2>1st Content Area</h2>
      <p>The Test text goes here</p>
    </div>

    <div id="second">
      <h2>2nd Content Area</h2>
      <p>The Test text goes here</p>
    </div>

    <div id="third">
      <h2>3rd Content Area</h2>
      <p>The Test text goes here</p>
    </div>

    <div id="forth">
      <h2>4th Content Area</h2>
      <p>The Test text goes here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <h4>Footer</h4>
    <p>Footer text</p>
  </div>

</div>
```